# spring boot: how to verify env variables?

Tags: spring-boot

Is it possible to check env vars on startup in Spring Boot?
For example config looks like this:

```yaml
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: ${MONGODB_URI}
  rabbitmq:
    addresses: ${RMQ_CLUSTER_ADDRESSES}
```

I want the app to not start if one of var is not exists.

Comment: I don't think so. as these are system env var, you can simply write a bash script to check the relevant variables are set or not then run the application through the script

Comment: @namila007 it need to synchronize vars with script manually, not convenient

Comment: actually app will fails when the relevant vars are not available. if u need, in the app create a manual mongo configuration and read the value and check whether the var is null or not and proceed